# Converting UTC to UNIX epoch in milliseconds

Tags: powershell, time

The following code produces Unix epoch time in seconds and strips the decimal place to give milliseconds.

It works **most** of the time but throws an error occasionally.  Execute and you'll see the error.

I've been unable to figure out why or a solution.  Any suggestions?

```
 while (1 -ne 0) {
(Get-Date (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() -UFormat %s).replace(',', '').replace('.', '').SubString(0,13)
}
```

Comment: That solution inserted to the while loop does not produce an error.  I need to re-read it a few times as I've not got my head around it yet.  Thank-you very much!

Comment: you don't need a while loop, as it is simply a conversion from DateTime object to Unix timestamp and vice-versa.

Comment: The while loop was just to show that the conversion works 99% of the time but errors occasionally.

Comment: Ah of course. Didn't realize that when I did the comment.